# Using regex in Bash with mapfile

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

**Edit 2**:

Minimal input file: `input/input.txt`

```
#-----------
snapshot=83
#-----------
time=30142088
mem_heap_B=20224
mem_heap_extra_B=8
mem_stacks_B=240480
heap_tree=empty
#-----------
snapshot=84
#-----------
time=30408368
mem_heap_B=20224
mem_heap_extra_B=8
mem_stacks_B=240552
heap_tree=empty
#-----------
snapshot=85
#-----------
time=30674648
mem_heap_B=20224
mem_heap_extra_B=8
mem_stacks_B=240464
heap_tree=empty
#-----------
snapshot=86
#-----------
```

Actual output:

```
input.txt/*
time, heap, stack


input/input.txt
time, heap, stack
30674648, 20224, 240464


input/input.txt
time, heap, stack
input/input.txt
time, heap, stack
input/input.txt
time, heap, stack
30674648, 20224, 240464
```

Expected output:

```
input.txt
time, heap, stack,
30142088, 20224, 240480
30408368, 20224, 240552
30674648, 20224, 240464
```

**Edit**: Originally, the problem may have been due to Bash's regex's lack of multiline capability. However, after stripping newlines from the text, the problem remains, with the exception that the output now has between one to five lines instead of zero.

I'm trying to write a Bash script to parse a text file into a desirable CSV file with the needed information.

As part of the script, I iterate through *n* files. Each of the files contains *m* matches for a given regex, and each match contains three capture groups.

I want to format the three capture groups into a CSV row, then concatenate all the rows of all the matches of all the files and write them to a `*.csv` file.

I'm quite comfortable using Regex in high level languages such as Kotlin or C#, however I have no experience with Regex in Bash. I used [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251031) answer as a starting point, however it doesn't seem to be working for me (`mapfile -t matches < <( format_row "$text" "$regex" )` doesn't do anything.

Here's the full code with the relevant portion noted:

```
#!/bin/bash


# RELEVANT CODE BELOW

regex="time=([0-9]+)\nmem_heap_B=([0-9]+)\n.*\nmem_stacks_B=([0-9]+)"

format_row() {
    local s=$1 regex=$2
    while [[ $s =~ $regex ]]
    do
            time="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
            heap="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
            stack="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"

            echo "${time}, ${heap}, ${stack}"
            echo ""

            s=${s#*"${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"}
    done
}

for file in $1/*
do
    echo "Parsing ${file}..."

    echo $file >> $2
    echo "time, heap, stack" >> $2

    text=$(<${file})
    mapfile -t matches < <( format_row "$text" "$regex" )

    printf "%s\n" "${matches[@]}" >> $2
    echo "" >> $2
done


echo ""
echo "Done"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about isolate only the problematic code instead of the whole script ?   
Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). bash regex are not multi-line mode capable

Comment: What may be happening is you are assuming you know the regex language that bash implements.  It may be quite different from what you are used to.  I don't know what bash uses, but it may be similar to https://linuxize.com/post/regular-expressions-in-grep/

Comment: perl might give you results more like what you're used to?

Comment: @GillesQuenot Apologies; I madde sure to make it complete but forgot to make it minimal. I edited my question to minimize the code. And thanks! I didn't know about the multi-line-mode capability

Comment: @JoelFan ya I think that's the case it turns out, I'm used to using "standard" high-level regex. Thanks!

Comment: @GillesQuenot how would I go about using grep with perl regex to implement this?

Comment: I think they're suggesting to use perl, not bash or grep

Comment: @JoelFan ah ok, I've never used Perl before so I'd rather use Bash if possible. Also, if I remove the newlines from the regex, I actually get the last match of each file, but no matches in the rest of the file. Is this still because of the multiline-ness or is it because of my code? Does a multiline regex refer to the regex itself having multiple lines or the input file?

Comment: It usually refers to the input (which is not a "file" usually, but rather a string)

Comment: @GillesQuenot Per my edit, I removed all newlines from the text. However, the problem still remains, so there's a problem with my regex looping code apparently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. Although bash's `=~` operator can match newlines, it does not understand the `\n` escape sequence. You have to use actual newlines in your regex. This can also be achieved by C-style strings `$'\n'`.
2. The regex quantifier `*` is greedy. When matching ...
   `[[ "a=1,b=1  a=2,b=2  a=3,b=3" =~ a=(.).*b=(.) ]]`
   ... you end up with `BATCH_REMATCH=(1 3)` instead of `(1 1)`.
   In other regex dialects like PCRE you could use the non-greedy quantifier `*?`. However, in bash we have to use a workaround and have to replace `.*` with something that cannot match more than wanted, for instance
   `[[ "a=1,b=1  a=2,b=2  a=3,b=3" =~ a=(.)[^=]*b=(.) ]]`
   In your case we have to make sure that the next `mem_stacks` is not matched

As you didn't post any example input and expected output, I can only guess. However, I assume the following regex could work for you:

```
regex=$'time=([0-9]+)
mem_heap_B=([0-9]+)
([^\n]*\n){TODO set number of lines allowed here}
mem_stacks_B=([0-9]+)'
```

Note that now you have to use `BASH_REMATCH[4]` instead of `[3]`.

At the marked location you have to insert the numbers of lines allowed between `mem_heap` and `mem_stacks`. The number can be constant (e.g. `{5}`) or a range (e.g. `{1,10}`). In case of ranges you have to make sure that the maximum bound is not so high that you could accidentally skip the next `mem_stacks` and match another `mem_stacks` instead. Thus, in case of ranges it might be more appropriate to use two matches. Something like

```
regex1='time=([0-9]+)
mem_heap_B=([0-9]+)'
regex2='mem_stacks_B=([0-9]+)'

while
  [[ "$s" =~ $regex1 ]] &&
  time="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" &&
  heap="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" &&
  [[ "$s" =~ $regex2 ]] &&
  stack="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
do
  echo "$time, $heap, $stack"
  s="${s#*$stack}"
done >> "$2"
```

**By the way:**

- https://www.shellcheck.net/ helps you to make your script more robust.
  First and foremost: quote your variables.
- You can use `do cmd1; cmd2 done >> file` instead of `do cmd1 >> file; cmd2 >> file; done`.
- `mapfile -t matches < <(format_row "$text" "$regex")`
  `printf "%s\n" "${matches[@]}" >> "$2"`
  could be written as just
  `format_row "$text" "$regex" >> "$2"`